# How do I call a list from another function in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list in a function that I have appended values into, now I am trying to wonder how I can call that list in another function.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what doesn't work for you?

Comment: `call` is something you do to functions to execute them. It's not clear what you mean in the context of a list. Are you just trying to access the list?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Hello, yes, I have created a list in one function, and I would like to be able to access that list in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a new global variable to point your list inside the function.

```
pointedList = []
copiedList = []

def function():
    x = []
    x.append("Something")

    pointedList = x #Changes made to pointedList will change values in x
    copiedList = x.copy() #Changes made to copiedList will not reflect in x

    '''
    Rest of the program
    '''

def newFunction():
    '''
    You can use pointedList and copiedList here
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand you but you can `return` that list and use it into another function.

```
def function():
    x=[]
    for i in range(5):
        x.append(i)
return x

def print_function():
    x=function()
    print(x)
return
```